# JAR Signing: How long can a certificate last?

Tags: jar-signing

I understand that when signing a JAR, it is possible to extend  the default certificate expiration date of of 90 days by using `-validity`.

Since what I'm making is an embedded system, I would like to have the certificate last indefinitely, or at least several years. Having to constantly resign the JAR's would be dangerous.

Is there a way to make the time infinite or is simply putting a few thousand days the best route?

Edit:

It is my intent to use a certificate authority, specifically Verisign.

Comment: Are you self signing the certificate, or getting it from a certificate authority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a certificate of a certificate authority you will usually find the maximum period in the authorities policy.

If you use a self-signed certificate, then you can choose the duration by yourself only limited by the specification.